# Group algebra and polynomial algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, monoid

It occurred to me that since the group algebra of $\mathbb{Z}$, $k\mathbb{Z}$, has multiplication 
$$\left(\sum _{n\in \mathbb Z} a_n n\right)\cdotp \left(\sum _{n\in \mathbb Z} b_n n\right)=\left(\sum _{n\in \mathbb Z} \sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} a_k b_{n-k} n\right)$$
we can think of the polynomial algebra $k\left[X\right]$ as a subalgebra of $k\mathbb{Z}$ spanned by the non-negative elements.

Since the group algebra construction works for monoids just as well, can we then think of the polynomial algebra $k\left[X\right]$ as $k\mathbb{N}$ as the "monoid algebra" of the natural numbers? This would be quite a neat definition of the polynomial algebra, if it works, I think.

Comment: Yes, it works exactly as you've described. Indeed $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\cong k[\Bbb{N}^n]$.

Comment: A conceptual proof would be that the monoid algebra construction is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $k$-algebras to monoids (also from commutative $k$-algebras to commutative monoids), and $\Bbb{N}^n$ is the free commutative monoid on $n$ elements, so $k[\Bbb{N}^n]$ will be the free commutative $k$-algebra on $n$ elements.

Comment: @jgon: it might be a kindness to point out which forgetful functor you are talking about (namely the one that forgets the additive structure).

Comment: @RobArthan good point, I indeed meant the one that sends a ring to its multiplicative monoid, forgetting the additive structure.